# VueJS pass all props to child component

Tags: javascript, rest, vue.js

I am quite new to VueJS. In react you can easily use rest params for passing props to children. Is there a similar pattern in Vue?

Consider this parent component that has a few children components:

```
<template>
<header class="primary-nav">
<search-bar :config="searchBar"><search-bar>
//          ^^^^ this becomes the key on the props for SearchBar
header>
</template>

export default {
  data(){
    return {
      ... a few components ...
      searchBar : {
        model: '',
        name: 'search-bar',
        placeholder: 'Search Away',
        required:true,
        another: true
        andanother: true,
        andonemoreanotherone:true,
        thiscouldbehundredsofprops:true
      }
    }
  }
}

<template>
    <div :class="name">
        <form action="/s" method="post">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <label :for="config.name" class="icon-search">{{config.label}}</label>
            <text-input :config="computedTextInputProps"></text-input>
                        //^^^^ and so on. I don't like this config-dot property structure.
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

  export default {
    props: {
        name: String,
        required: Boolean,
        placeholder: String,
        model: String,
    },
    computed: {
     computedtextInputProps(){
       return justThePropsNeededForTheTextInput
     }
    }
 ...
```

What I don't like is that the props are named-spaced with the key `config`, or any other arbitrary key. The text-input component ( not shown ) is a glorified `input` field that can take a number of attributes. I could flatten the props when the component is created, but is that generally a good idea?

I am surprised this question hasn't been asked before.

Thanks.

**Edit: 10-06-2017**

Related: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4962

Comment: You can pass an object as a prop, containing all needed key-value pairs.

Comment: That's what I am I have illustrated here. The :config key is the prop key on the child. Which is not what I want.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Parent component**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <child-component v-bind="propsToPass"></child-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ChildComponent from './components/child-component/child-component'

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
      ChildComponent
    },
    data () {
      return {
        propsToPass: {
          name: 'John',
          last_name: 'Doe',
          age: '29',
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Child Component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>I am {{name}} {{last_name}} and i am {{age}} old</p>
    <another-child v-bind="$props"></another-child> <!-- another child here and we pass all props -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import AnotherChild from "../another-child/another-child";
  export default {
    components: {AnotherChild},
    props: ['name', 'last_name', 'age'],
  }
</script>
```

**Another Child component inside the  above component**

```
<template>
    <h1>I am saying it again: I am {{name}} {{last_name}} and i am {{age}} old</h1>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      props: ['name', 'last_name', 'age']
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It should be `v-bind="$attrs"`  in vue 2.2.+

Comment: Nope, $attrs indicate all passed attributes that are not declared as props.

Comment: it's confusing because to achieve what the OP is asking, you kind of have to use a combination of `$attrs` and `$props` because you might not know all the possible props (attrs? <--see, confusing) which a consumer might try to use on your component.

Comment: Using this, the attributes are visible in generated html, but if we simply add `inheritAttrs: false` to component definition, then they are not visible in html, but still work. I believe this is neater.

Comment: Is it still possible to get IntelliSense when using this forwarding approach? Following your example, how can I get IntelliSense/ code completion when working with child component inside the parent component? When working with child component, I would like to see all the available props/ listeners that are inherited

Answer (score 19):

**Parent component**

You can pass as many props as you want to child component

[image]

**Child Component**

Once you are satisfied with all the props, then you can use `v-bind="$props"` inside your child component to retrieve all the props.

[image]

**Final Result:**

[image]

Done:)

Comment: It should be `v-bind="$attrs"`  in vue 2.2.+

Answer (score 15):

In `Vue 2.6+`, in addition to attributes passing,
events/listeners can be also passed to child components.

#### Parent component

```
<template>
    <div>
       <Button @click="onClick">Click here</Button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Button from "./Button.vue";
export default {
    methods:{
        onClick(evt) {
            // handle click event here
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

#### Child component

`Button.vue`

```
<template>
    <button v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners">
        <slot />
    </button>
</template>
```

### Update [2021-08-14]:

In Vue 3, `$listeners` will be removed. `$attrs` will have both listeners and attributes passing to the child component.

#### Child component

`Button.vue`

```
<template>
    <button v-bind="$attrs">
        <slot />
    </button>
</template>
```

[Migration Guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/listeners-removed.html#_3-x-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

```
v-bind="[$attrs, $props]"
```

This one works for me. $attrs doesn't include props.

Answer (score 0):

In the child component, you can bind $attrs and $props.

```
<template>
    <button v-bind="[$props,$attrs]" v-on="$listeners">
        <slot />
    </button>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Confusion between props and attrs.

Which you need to use depends on what sort of child component you're passing to.

Probably the most common use-case for passing all props to a child component is for **recursive components**.

Imagine a tree component which, when a branch is expanded, should load another instance of the same component under itself, as a sub-branch.

In this situation you probably want to pass all (or most) of the props originally passed into the parent component, into the child.

For this, use `v-bind='$props'` on the reference to the child component in the parent.

You can supplement this with other props, or overrides to props included in `$props`, as necessary.

`$attrs`, on the other hand, concerns attributes i.e. props that were passed into the component but which are not declared (expected) by the component. These are automatically registered on the component's root element, and the most common example is to pass CSS classes.

To pass *both* props and attrs, as @donghoon-song and @nisar-ahmed point out in their answers, use `v-bind='[$props, $attrs]`.